# Java Shut the Box

Tags: java, arrays

Im writing a program similar to a game called shut the box. The game asks the player to roll 2 die, and then the player chooses to cover both numbers individually (in the boolean array), or the total of the two.

I'm having difficulty returning two values of the int method roll() which is supposed to roll two die.

Heres my code for the main class:

```
public class clacker {

    private int play;
    private int die1;
    private int die2;
    private boolean[] table;
    private final int high = 6;
    private final int low = 1;
    private int range;

    public clacker()
    {
        range = high-low+1;
        table = new boolean[13];
        play = 0;
    }

    public void roll()
    {
        die1 = (int)(Math.random()*range+low);
        die2 = (int)(Math.random()*range+low);

    }

    public void value(char ch)
    {
        if(ch == 'i' || ch == 'I')
        {
            table[die1] = true;
            table[die2] = true;
            displayBoard();
        }
        else if(ch == 'T' || ch == 't')
        {
            table[die1+die2] = true;
            displayBoard();

        }
        else
        {
            roll();
        }
    }

    public void displayBoard()
    {
        for(int i = 1; i<table.length; i++)
        {
            if(table[i] == false)
            {
                System.out.print("   " + i + "   ");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print("   /   ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and for the test class:

```
public class clackerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        clacker oo = new clacker();

        EasyReader kboard = new EasyReader();
        System.out.println("Press anything to roll the dice. ");
        char roll= kboard.readChar();

        int dice1 = oo.roll();
        int dice2 = oo.roll();
        System.out.println("You rolled " + dice1 + " and a " + dice2 + "!");

        System.out.println("Cover Individual or Total: (enter i or t)");
        char roll2 = kboard.readChar();
    }
}
```

Comment: You'd need to either return an array with both values, or an object that contains the values. Or manage that elsewhere as your `main` class applies and just return a single value--right now you're trying to do both at once.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just `roll()` twice? Modify `roll()` to return **one** int.

```
public int roll() {
  return (int)(Math.random()*range+low);
}
```

And now, from within clackerTest (java conventions dictates you name this ClackerTest):

```
int dice1 = oo.roll();
int dice2 = oo.roll();
```